# How to restore Julia history file from a running session?

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Halp! I accidentally deleted my `~/.julia/logs` folder.

BUT the good news is I have several running julia sessions up, which seem to have some memory of the julia REPL history.

Does anyone know if there's a way to reverse-dump a history file from the running julia process's state somehow? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should store it back to a file which can then be put in `.julia/logs/repl_history.jl`:

```
function restore_repl_history()
    hist = Base.active_repl.interface.modes[1].hist
    open("restored_history.jl", "w") do io
        for (mode, cont) in zip(hist.modes, hist.history)
            println(io, "# time: $(Libc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", time()))")
            println(io, "# mode: $mode")
            s = join(split(cont, '\n'), "\n\t")
            println(io, "\t", s)
        end
    end
end
```